# Can I map rows/models into a dictionary keyed by an enum column (or logic on a string column) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a table that looks like:

```
PERSON        | STATUS | ICE CREAM FLAVOR TYPE | FAVORITE ICE CREAM FLAVOR

Alice         | ALIVE  | CHOCOLATE             | Dark chocolate
Bobby         | ALIVE  | CHOCOLATE             | Mint chocolate
Olive         | DEAD   | BAD TASTE             | Vanilla
Hilbertonious | ALIVE  | BAD TASTE             | Mango strawberry
```

and I want to get from this a count of living people by ice cream flavor by ice cream flavor type. E.g., for the above data, it would be:

```
{ CHOCOLATE: { "Dark chocolate": 1, "Mint chocolate": 1 } }, BAD TASTE: { "Mango strawberry": 1 }}
```

(Olive is excluded because they are dead, presumably from the sheer boredom of eating vanilla ice cream)

Anyhow, filtering by Status and breaking down counts by favorite ice cream flavor is straightforward (this is what I have so far):

```
from collections import Counter
from a_sql_alchemy_wrapper.models import Person, Session

session = Session()
ice_cream_flavors_with_counts = Counter(
    person.favorite_ice_cream_flavor for patient in
    session.query(Person)
        .filter(
            Person.status == Person.PersonStatus.alive
        )
        .all()
    )
```

Which gets me an ice cream flavor to count dictionary:

```
{ "Mint chocolate": 1, "Dark chocolate": 1, "Mango strawberry": 1}
```

For the next step, breaking down ice cream flavor by ice cream flavor type, is there some streaming code I could write in Python or SQLAlchemy to group favorite ice cream flavors on the fly into their types?

I don't *actually* want to use the ice cream flavor type enum column if I can avoid it (it doesn't exist yet and probably shouldn't be added since it's smarter to just have ice cream flavors map to types in their own table). Ideally, I'd be able to just check the suffix of the favorite ice cream flavor string and break it down based on the last word in the string.

Is there a way to do this grouping nicely, in a streaming fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case statement like this:

```py
whens={
    'Dark chocolate': 'CHOCOLATE', 
    'Mint chocolate': 'CHOCOLATE',
    'Mango strawberry': 'BAD_TASTE'
}

from sqlalchemy import case

session.query(Person, case(whens=whens, value=Person.favorite_ice_cream_flavor).label('flavor_type')).all()
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case

Comment: What if I don't know all possible flavors that could end in 'chocolate'? Is there a way for me to do this dynamically?

Comment: Use `value=func.regexp_replace(Person.favorite_ice_cream_flavor, '^.* ', '')` to apply the case to the last word, ie. `whens={'chocolate': 'CHOCOLATE'}`.  I don't know why you need this, maybe to avoid the ENUM just try to get by with manipulating the property in python.